# User control in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webusercontrol

I have a datebox user control in grid view and one of the properties is RowID. From Gridview I am passing the Row ID to the datebox as

```
<uc2:datePage1 ID="txtSubToSA" RowID=<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>   runat="server" Enabled="true" Text= '<%#Eval("SUBMITTED_TO_SA") %>' />
```

in the pageload of the usercontrol I am adding attribute to call a javascript function like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "getRow(" + RowID + ")");

    }
  public int RowID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Now when I make a change in the datebox of the gridview, no matter what row it is it always gives takes RowID of 0 and do not recognize changes I made in other rows. What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the `onchange` attribute in the `Load` event handler, before the `RowId` has been set - which will happend during databinding.  You could perhaps override `DataBind` and set the attribute after databinding is complete:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    base.DataBind();
    txtDate.Attributes.Add(...);
}
```

Comment: you mean DataBind of the usercontrol or of the Gridview? Usercontrol is a simple textbox and ajax control calender extender. This usercontrol is used in the various columns of the gridview. I want to fire onchange event on the row in which the text of textbox user control value is changed.

Comment: I resolved it by setting in the attribute  in the property rather than in the page load. Thanks for the tip! This is what I did and it worked.  'code'public int RowID
        {
           

            set
            {
                txtDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "getRow(" + value + ")");
            }
        }

Comment: @user799891 - I meant the `DataBind` method of the UserControl - you need to be in the UserControl to have access to txtDate.  But your solution of adding the attribute in the property setter will work too - possibly a better solution as it will work if the RowId is set programatically rather than using databinding.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead - Move the code from

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "getRow(" + RowID + ")");
}
```

to

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", "getRow(" + RowID + ")");
}
```

The Page Load complete event is fired after the data is loaded.